# Connectin host and virtual machine in VMware

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have host Win 8 that runs WinXP VMWare machine. I would like to have easy copy files from one machine to another using network. I have default networking params in my WinXP machine. Unfortunately ping not finds machines each other from both sides. WinXP config:
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.196.152
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.196.2
```

How to solve connectivity problem?

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot from the network adapter settings of the virtual machine, please.

Comment: I have attached in problem description

Comment: Windows often blocks ping in the firewall. Do other protocols work?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the VM in VMWare Workstation go to Settings - Network Adapter and set Network Connection to "Bridged". You can only do this when the VM is powered off.

Answer (score 0):

It is vital that VMware Tools is installed in the VM.
Have you done it? Is the Network driver in the VM working OK?
From inside the VM do you see a working network interface?
[image]